# What think tanks and newspapers that are associated with Macron's En Marche and pan-European Renaissance?

Tags: media, europe, france, reference-request, liberalism

What think tanks are associated with Macron's En Marche and pan-European Renaissance? What newspapers (possibly French) are read by the voters/supporters of En Marche and Renaissance?

Comment: Google it in French: "journaux pro macron".

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy "journaux pro macron" mostly turns up conspiracy rhetoric (where it's a convenient label for anyone who isn't for “us”, whoever “us” is).

Comment: My bad. I must have had a pre-Aug 2017 date filter on when I wrote that. For me that results in a bunch of links by mainstream media that discuss the press' pro-macron treatment. https://www.europe1.fr/emissions/Le-journal-des-medias/plusieurs-medias-accuses-de-soutenir-emmanuel-macron-3001487 https://www.liberation.fr/futurs/2016/07/12/ces-journaux-qui-en-pincent-pour-macron_1465762 https://www.marianne.net/politique/Macron-le-figaro-fan-se-macronise-et-la-droite-crise https://www.20minutes.fr/politique/1963647-20161117-macron-elus-patrons-medias-soutiens-candidat-hors-systeme etc.

Comment: Adding to this, and to the best of my knowledge while keeping in mind that as an expat I'm not paying that much attention, none of the French newspapers are explicitly pro-Macro, but the main contenders for a Pro-Macro label would be centrist outfits like L'Express and Le Monde. Several of the hosts and pundits on the BFM TV station also spring to mind.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy When I still read Le Monde regularly I do not remember it being pro Macron at all (if anything, it seemed to be markedly anti Macron). I haven't read it often since I moved away from France though

Comment: @DenisNardin: Then you should expand your horizons a little bit. Take the [first of the top 10 articles from today](https://www.lemonde.fr/politique/article/2020/07/25/jean-castex-se-deplace-a-nice-apres-plusieurs-episodes-de-violences_6047255_823448.html). The leg humping in the first two paragraphs was so excruciating that it's difficult to read further if you're anything aware of what the topic entails. It's all rubber stamping. And FFS: "l’ensauvagement"?!? Uncritically quoting that is a Le Pen victory that any self-respecting newspaper should be denouncing all over. Le Monde is a rag.

Comment: @DenisNardin: But in some sense, I'd agree with you. It's not so much that Le Monde is firmly into the LREM camp than it is that they're basically spineless. They'll rubber stamp anything center, left, or right, so long as it doesn't ruffle too many feathers. They don't have a shred of analysis or integrity to put forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About think tanks, the question is easy:

The Institut Montaigne: Laurent Bigorgne the director of the Institut was a supporter of EM

The Gracques which actively supported EM.

These two organisations represented the right-side of the "parti socialiste": We can say they are liberals (In France liberals are considered as rightist (or at least "centristes")).

Source (in french, and not free): https://www.monde-diplomatique.fr/2019/12/RZEPSKI/61104
Still in french
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_Bigorgne

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Gracques_(politique)#cite_note-VF-1

https://www.lemonde.fr/m-actu/article/2017/03/03/l-alliance-bayrou-macron-la-revanche-des-gracques_5088904_4497186.html

About newspapers which support Macron: I'm not an expert, but L'Express seems fit (The chief editor of this newspaper did a rap for Macron:
https://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2017/08/17/2629395-christophe-barbier-cree-malaise-imaginant-macron-train-rapper.html
https://rmc.bfmtv.com/emission/christophe-barbier-je-ne-suis-pas-macroniste-c-est-eventuellement-macron-qui-est-barbier-iste-1655526.html )

There are probably other candidates (le nouvel observateur, more anecdotally le 1), but it's less obvious

It's much harder to answer what is read by a Macron voter because his electorate has changed a lot since his election, but (personal point of view) I would say at the beginning Lemonde which was full of sympathy for him, and then, I don't know, I'm not even sure his voters read newspapers...

Comment: Thanks! And let sources be in French, now I am learning French from time to time. Sympathies for Macron and En Marche made me to do this. It is so fascinating that French culture and society again proved its strength, resilience and permanent modernity ("up-to-dateness") and generated this movement and ideas!

Comment: I would not consider that France "generated" these ideas. I would consider these liberal ideas come more from US and UK (Reagan and Tatcher).